# Cell.all() python gives OSError

Tags: python, module, wifi, cell

I am trying to get the output of Cell.all() function from the wifi module but it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "yea.py", line 3, in <module>
cell = Cell.all('wlp0s20u2')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wifi/scan.py", line 39, in all
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have been searching for a fix for a couple of hours now, and everything I found is related to the subprocess module. Is there a way to fix this (pass a shell=True argument) or does anybody know a module similar to wifi that i could use for a simple wifi mapping script?

P.S. If it is relevant I'm using Solus 3 linux distro.

Comment: Look at line 38 of `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wifi/scan.py` and see what command it is trying to run. The error says that the executable cannot be found, so you probably need to install something like `wireless-tools` or similar.

Comment: Line 38 says : iwlist_scan = subprocess.check_output(['/sbin/iwlist', interface, 'scan'], raise InterfaceError(e.output.strip()). wireless-tools is already installed.